# Removing a Web Front-End server from Farm (Load Balancing)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, load-balancing

I am currently working on a project where we have developed a portal on SharePoint. Currently we have two servers which is using Load Balancing. We're experiencing a lot of difficulties connected to this, so we are thinking about removing one of the Web Front-End servers from the farm.

Could this cause any kind of problems that you can think of? I want to be sure before I recommend to this to our client. Anything you could think of would be great. Also pro's you can think of by doing this is appreciated.

The load balancing was agreed on from the beginning of the project, before we came in as consultants.

(I know this could be posted on SharePoint.Stackexchange aswell, but this could be general knowledge for anyone else as well.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/22883/807

Answer (score 1):

Since "two servers" is not a good idea anyway (you'd normally create at minimum a three server farm - two load balanced web front-ends and one indexing/job server), you can easily merge them into one server. Steps would be like this:
- enable all the services on the server which stays there
- remove the other server from "web front-end" role 
- uninstall sharepoint from the other server

This might require recreation of your shared services provider if you are hosting some of the SSP things on the server you are removing.